# Can I "clear up" the audio I'm hearing from a video clip in my browser?

Tags: audio, browser, filter, audacity

I'm listening to some recording of a talk, which was made with a microphone far from the speaker; there's some noise and perhaps a bit of echo and it's not super clear. Now, if this were just an audio file on my PC, I would (try to) use Audacity which is supposed to be able to help. But - this is a video clip played by some web page on my browser, and I can't (or find it difficult to) download it.

Is there a way I could apply some kind of filtering on my outgoing audio to clear it up?

My system: Devuan GNU/Linux Excalibur (i.e. Debian Trixie without systemd) on an x86_64, with Cinnamon as the desktop environment. Sound server is pulseaudio.

Comment: Which sound server ? (No? - Jackd? - Pulseaudio? - Pipewire?…)

Comment: @MC68020: Pulse. That's the default, so I didn't mention it; now edited into the answer.

Comment: There are some approaches to applying filters to live streams with pulseaudio: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18958/realtime-noise-removal-with-pulseaudio https://askubuntu.com/questions/869822/how-to-add-a-low-pass-filter-to-a-system-wide-pulseaudio-profile https://askubuntu.com/questions/43950/how-can-i-apply-a-ladspa-plugin-to-a-pulseaudio-stream https://askubuntu.com/questions/31580/is-there-a-way-of-leveling-compressing-the-sound-system-wide

Answer (score 0):

You do need [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) or similar DAW app & [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/).

Doing a noise reduction on-the-fly is really hard.  You have to capture the stream first.
`ffmpeg -i "https://address.of/stream/here" -c copy "your_file.mkv"`

You must separate the audio/video. (.mkv, .mp4, .webm whatever you have)
`ffmpeg -i your_file.mkv -vn your_file.wav && ffmpeg -i your_file.mkv -an -c copy your_file.m4v`

Open the WAV in Audacity.  Zoom in a few times (Ctrl+1) and find a part with only 1-3 seconds of only the noise you want to eliminate, click and drag to select it.
[image: Select noise segment]

Go to: **Effect > Noise Reduction** and click the "Get Noise Profile" button.[image: Get noise profile]

Now, press **Ctrl + A** to select all.  Now go back to the **Effect > Noise Reduction** and click OK, just using the default settings.

It should look like this now, noise removed.
[image: Noise removed]

**File > Export > Export as WAV**
Name it: `NEW_your_file.wav`  You don't have to fill in the metadata.
[image: Export WAV]

Recompress the WAV:
`ffmpeg -i NEW_your_file.wav -c:a aac NEW_your_file.m4a`

Re-mux the video with new audio:
`ffmpeg -i your_file.m4v -i NEW_your_file.m4a -c copy your_new_file.mkv`

Noise reduced.

Comment: If I understood OP correctly, they just get no file. Meaning that they need to denoise on the fly the audio stream in realtime. I therefore do not think your answer correctly addresses the problem.

Comment: If that's the case, you have to capture the stream first.  `ffmpeg -i "https://address.of/stream/here" -c copy "output.mkv"`

Comment: I specifically said I don't have the audio as a file. If I could easily capture it I wouldn't ask this question. I'm sorry you took the time to write this detailed and informative answer... perhaps you could move it to a separate question? I'd upvote it...

Comment: It wasn't that much, no worries.  What's the problem with capture?   That's why I went ahead. It's nearly impossible, on-the-fly. I have a rough idea of how to attempt it...you will not succeed.  Capture is not hard.  If you can watch it, you can save it.  Anyone thinks I can't save your stream?  Try me.  Unless you don't have ANY write privileges on your end, you can get that data. Come and chat, I can show you how.  http://tinyurl.com/modulate-chat